# Alerts for new folders only

Tags: workflow, folder, approval

Would anyone know if there is a way to create an alert or a approval workflow anytime a folder is created in a document library. I am not interested in the actual documents at this point, just the creation of a folder in the main document library.

Answer (score 0):

In Sharepoint 2013, with workflow manager installed, you can create a workflow that start when an item is added to the library.

The workflow first check if the item content type is folder.

If its a folder, then the workflow can do other task like sending an email or assign a task for approval.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12615956/how-to-check-last-added-item-is-a-folder-or-not-in-sharepoint-event-receiver) which contains pretty much the same question like you got.

Here is the code you need inside your event receiver:

```
  public class ClassName : SPItemEventReceiver
  {
      public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
      {
           bool isFolder = (properties.ListItem.Folder != null);
      }
  }
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks Amal for the suggestion. I edited my post and I hope it's good now.